# What does "AL NG, LE" mean in the description of the city of Brindol in the "Red Hand of Doom" adventure book?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, published-adventures

Looking at the description for Brindol in [*Red Hand of Doom*](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/28797/Red-Hand-of-Doom-3e) (p. 9), it says:

> AL NG, LE

Any idea what these mean?

I assume AL is Adventurer's League but not sure about the rest.

The full text reads:

> **Brindol (Small City):** Conventional, nonstandard; AL NG, LE;
>   15,000 gp limit; Assets 6,300,000 gp; Population 8,400; [...]

Comment: Just a note: "Adventurers League", referring to the organized play system, is specifically a D&D 5e thing. Previous editions' organized play systems were differently named.

Answer (score 23):

*AL* here stands for *alignment*, and *NG* and *LE* stand for the alignments *neutral good* and *lawful evil*, respectively. (While the *Dungeon Master's Guide* doesn't go so far as to define *AL* when used this way as specifically meaning alignment, *AL* is used to mean *alignment* by the *Dungeon Master's Guide* in several places like in creature stat blocks on 201 *et al.* Similar town statblocks are used in many official *3.5* products, and *Red Hand of Doom* doesn't appear to introduce any new rules in this regard.)

These alignments when used in conjunction with a town's statblock indicate the alignments of Brindol's power centers—how the folks in charge run the town. The *DMG* covers what this means in greater and better detail, but, in part, it says that a "neutral good power center rarely influences the residents of the community other than to help them when they are in need" and that a "community with a lawful evil power center usually has a codified set of laws, which most people obey out of fear of harsh punishment" (138).

The town's conventional power center is Lord Kerden Jarmaath and his forces (they're NG in alignment), while the town's nonstandard power center is Lady Verrasa Kaal and her forces (they're the LE bunch).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with:

> Alignment: Neutral Good, Lawful Evil

Comment: This is correct, but guessing is not appropriate for an answer on this site.

Comment: @Snowcrash do you have access to, or a copy of, the DMG for D&D 3.5?